# Why does a vertical scrollbar appear on the page?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scrollbar, overflow

I am creating a sample `flexbox` project named Catty Music.
What i see is that a vertical scrollbar appears. What I'm trying to do is to have a fixed `div` with player controls at the bottom with `90px` height and a scrollable main content area located right above it, which will fill the remaining of the viewport height - without a scrollbar.
You can see a snapshot of it [HERE](https://liubomirwm-page-gists.gitlab.io/catty-music-scrollbar-issue/) or below snippet.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 90px);
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.music-head {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 280px;
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: #4e4e4e;
}

.music-list {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px 10px 0px;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 20px;
  min-height: 50px;
}

li p {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}

li span.catty-cloud {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  padding: 3px;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.catty-music {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.catty-music div:nth-child(1) {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.catty-music div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.catty-music div:nth-child(2) i.fa {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0 0.7em;
}
.catty-music div:nth-child(1) p:first-child {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

aside i.fa,
aside i.fab {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 90px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(61, 100, 158, 0.9);
}

footer img {
  width: 90px;
}

.footer-current-song-details {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.footer-music-controls {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 670px) {
  .music-head {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .catty-music {
    padding: 0;
  }

  .catty-music * {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .catty-music div:nth-child(1) p:first-child {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 10px 0 10px;
  }

  .music-head > img {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 50%;
  }

  .artist-details,
  .album-details {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside>
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <i class="fab fa-spotify"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> <i class="fab fa-soundcloud"></i>
  </aside>
  <section class="content">
    <div class="music-head">
      <img src="images/cattyboard.jpg" />
      <section class="catty-music">
        <div>
          <p>CattyBoard Top 100 Single Charts (11.06.36)</p>
          <p class="artist-details">Unknown Artist</p>
          <p class="album-details">2016 . Charts . 100 songs</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <i class="fa fa-play"> Play all</i>
          <i class="fa fa-plus"> Add to</i>
          <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"> More</i>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <ul class="music-list">
      <li>
        <p>1. One Dance</p>
        <p>Crake feat CatKid & Cyla</p>
        <p>2:54</p>
        <p><span class="catty-cloud">CATTY CLOUD SYNC</span></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>2. Panda</p>
        <p>Cattee</p>
        <p>4:06</p>
        <p><span class="catty-cloud">CATTY CLOUD SYNC</span></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>3. Can't Stop the Feeling!</p>
        <p>Catin Cimberlake</p>
        <p>3:56</p>
        <p><span class="catty-cloud">CATTY CLOUD SYNC</span></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>4. Work From Home</p>
        <p>Cat Harmony feat Colla</p>
        <p>3:34</p>
        <p><span class="catty-cloud">CATTY CLOUD SYNC</span></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>1. One Dance</p>
        <p>Crake feat CatKid & Cyla</p>
        <p>2:54</p>
        <p><span class="catty-cloud">CATTY CLOUD SYNC</span></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>2. Panda</p>
        <p>Cattee</p>
        <p>4:06</p>
        <p><span class="catty-cloud">CATTY CLOUD SYNC</span></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</main>
<footer>
  <img src="images/cattyboard.jpg" />
  <div class="footer-current-song-details">
    <p>If It Ain't Love</p>
    <p>Catson Derulo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-music-controls">
    <i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-pause"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-step-forward"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-redo"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-random sm-hide"></i>
  </div>
</footer>
```

It seems like there is an error with my calculations or the browser's calculations.
What i see is that the sum of the `<main>` and the `<footer>` elements on my PC is 744px. `window.innerHeight` also gives 744px. The `<html>` element also takes 744px height. I don't know from where does this scrollbar appear. Firefox DevTools has a sticker on the `<html>` element which says "This element is causing an element to overflow". `<html>` is the root element, isn't it? So what outer element is made to overflow by the `<html>` element?

I would be glad if anyone helps me find out what's going on here.

Comment: We don’t want “snapshots” of your problem on external sites, a proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly into your question.

Comment: @CBroe i have added a Stack Snippet.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! In addition to my error there seems to be a bug involved either in Chrome or Firefox (they haven't resolved to which is the correct implementatiion).
You can see here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1720680
And here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68391656/why-does-a-vertical-scrollbar-appear-on-the-page#comment120870363_68391803

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `padding: 10px` from the footer. So you have to change the calculation for `main` to `height: calc(100vh - 110px)` (`90px` + 2x `10px`).

**Working example:**

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 110px);
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.music-head {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 280px;
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: #4e4e4e;
}

.music-list {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px 10px 0px;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 20px;
  min-height: 50px;
}

li p {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}

li span.catty-cloud {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  padding: 3px;
}

li:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.catty-music {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.catty-music div:nth-child(1) {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.catty-music div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.catty-music div:nth-child(2) i.fa {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0 0.7em;
}
.catty-music div:nth-child(1) p:first-child {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

aside i.fa,
aside i.fab {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 90px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(61, 100, 158, 0.9);
}

footer img {
  width: 90px;
}

.footer-current-song-details {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.footer-music-controls {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 670px) {
  .music-head {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .catty-music {
    padding: 0;
  }

  .catty-music * {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .catty-music div:nth-child(1) p:first-child {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 10px 0 10px;
  }

  .music-head > img {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 50%;
  }

  .artist-details,
  .album-details {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <aside>
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <i class="fab fa-spotify"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> <i class="fab fa-soundcloud"></i>
  </aside>
  <section class="content">
    <div class="music-head">
      <img src="images/cattyboard.jpg" />
      <section class="catty-music">
        <div>
          <p>CattyBoard Top 100 Single Charts (11.06.36)</p>
          <p class="artist-details">Unknown Artist</p>
          <p class="album-details">2016 . Charts . 100 songs</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <i class="fa fa-play"> Play all</i>
          <i class="fa fa-plus"> Add to</i>
          <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"> More</i>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <ul class="music-list">
      <li>
        <p>1. One Dance</p>
        <p>Crake feat CatKid & Cyla</p>
        <p>2:54</p>
        <p><span class="catty-cloud">CATTY CLOUD SYNC</span></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>2. Panda</p>
        <p>Cattee</p>
        <p>4:06</p>
        <p><span class="catty-cloud">CATTY CLOUD SYNC</span></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>3. Can't Stop the Feeling!</p>
        <p>Catin Cimberlake</p>
        <p>3:56</p>
        <p><span class="catty-cloud">CATTY CLOUD SYNC</span></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>4. Work From Home</p>
        <p>Cat Harmony feat Colla</p>
        <p>3:34</p>
        <p><span class="catty-cloud">CATTY CLOUD SYNC</span></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>1. One Dance</p>
        <p>Crake feat CatKid & Cyla</p>
        <p>2:54</p>
        <p><span class="catty-cloud">CATTY CLOUD SYNC</span></p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>2. Panda</p>
        <p>Cattee</p>
        <p>4:06</p>
        <p><span class="catty-cloud">CATTY CLOUD SYNC</span></p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</main>
<footer>
  <img src="images/cattyboard.jpg" />
  <div class="footer-current-song-details">
    <p>If It Ain't Love</p>
    <p>Catson Derulo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-music-controls">
    <i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-pause"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-step-forward"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-redo"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-random sm-hide"></i>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Ah! I see! I was thinking that with `box-sizing: border-box` the padding will subtract from the 90px height. However `flex-basis` seems to not work that way.
It is interesting to me that if I add height:90px then it changes to 70px height + 2x10px padding, but still the `calc(100vh - 90px)` gives scrollbar.

Comment: So a bug seems to be part of the issue here. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1720680